# Are there any (non-GPL) options for MP4/H264 video plugins for embedded chromium?

Tags: video, html, mp4

I am looking at building an application that will be bundled with CEF (Chromium Embedded Framework). One of the things I'd like to do with this application is run some videos. However, since I will be distributing this non-open-source product, GPL code is not acceptable. The only plugin that I know of that works with CEF is a GPL mp4/h264 codec (used in FFMPEG & VLC).

I'm willing to purchase a plugin, but I haven't been able to find any commercial options. If there was a reasonable commercial option that took care of any mpeg-la licensing along with the licensing costs that would be fantastic. Is there such a thing?

I know there is a non-GPL open source mp4/h264 codec: [openh264](https://github.com/cisco/openh264). Has this ever been bundled into a Chromium-compatible plugin?